# Why can't I get ID attribute of a specific span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple `jQuery` code that should be getting the `ID` attribute of selected `span`. However it's not working.

I tried to get the `ID` number of the div that contains my `span`, it is working. I couldn't get what's wrong.

```
$("span.colorbox").on("click",function(){
        var secilirenk = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Note that I'm outputtig this `HTML` via an `on("click",function()` function.

```
var count = 1;

$(".kaydet").on("click",function(){

$(".bolgeler").append("<div class='" + count +"' style='display:block; float:left;'></div>");

$("."+count).append("<span class='colorbox' id='' style='display:inline-block; border: 1px solid gray;'>");

var kuturengi = $("#color").val();
$("."+count).find(".colorbox").css("background-color",kuturengi);
$("."+count).find(".colorbox").attr("id",kuturengi);

    var bolgeadi = $("#bismi").val();
$("."+count).append("<p style='display:inline-block; margin-right:15px;'>" + bolgeadi + "</p>");    
count++;   

    $('#bolgeolustur').attr("style","display:inline-block;");
    $('#bolge').attr("style","display:none;");
});
```

Output:

```
<div class="1" style="display:block; float:left;"><span class="colorbox" id="#123456" style="margin-top: 100px;display: inline-block;border: 1px solid gray;background-color: rgb(18, 52, 86);"></span><p style="display:inline-block; margin-right:15px;">asd</p></div>
```

`Tl;dr:` I want to get the `ID` attribute of the span that dynamically created by other on click function when I click on it.

Comment: How can you tell it is not working? That "click" handler for "span.colorbox" doesn't do anything.

Comment: What's the point of `$(this).attr("id")`? Just use `this.id`. And `prop` would be better than `attr`.

Comment: share the html for this

Comment: @Pointy I consol.log'ed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues:
1- You didn't close your span tag
2- You need to use delegate
3- put them into document ready

```
$("body").delegate("span.colorbox","click",function(){
        var secilirenk = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(secilirenk);
});
```

This works: https://jsfiddle.net/9bowx36r/

Answer (score 1):

`var count = 1; $("."+count)` is not a valid CSS selector.

In CSS, identifiers can't begin with a digit, but you can escape it:

```
$(".1") // wrong
$(".\\31 ") // ok
$(".\\000031") // ok
```

Or consider using `CSS.escape`:

```
$("." + CSS.escape(count)) // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

when generating dynamic content, the traditional on `CLICK` won't work because it applies to anything that is ALREADY in DOM.

try this instead:

```
$(document).on("click","span.colorbox",function(){
      var secilirenk = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(secilirenk);
});
```